# How to remove small lines created within the merged polygon using JTS

Tags: java, jts

I am using UnaryOp.union method provided by JTS library to merge a group of geomery objects into a single geometry object. However after merging the polygon, there are small lines visible within the polygon and I am looking for some thoughts on how to remove all those small lines?
Here is the screenshot

**Group of Polygons:**

[image]

**Merged Polygon with small lines within the polygon:**

[image]

**Code snippet:**

```
UnaryUnionOp.union(jtsGeometries);
```